# DLL without exported functions?

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport

I've snooped around a little bit in MS-Office DLLs, and I noticed that some of the DLLs don't have any exported functions. What I don't quite understand, how an application can use these DLLs without any functions exported ?!

I mean, the dllmain() does get executed on LoadLibrary(), but whats the point? Why would anyone create a DLL without exported functions?

thanks! :-)

Comment: Do they happen to have any embedded resources? Sometimes it's for the embedded icons, images, etc., e.g. `C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll`

Comment: @Mehrdad - The DLLs doesn't contain any resources..
@ildjarn - From when I know COM servers must at least export DllRegisterServer() & DllUnregisterServer(), am I right?

Comment: @TCS: If possible, would you mind saying which DLL this is? I'm curious now...

Comment: @TCS - no resources whatsoever? I find that very odd.

Comment: @TCS : Only if the COM server supports self-registration; those are not required otherwise.

Comment: @ildjarn: ehrm? Sorry? And COM DLLs don't require an exported factory (`DllGetClassObject`) function since ... when?

Comment: @ildjarn: please, sources. I know that self-registration is optional. But your claim is that it's a COM server without exports. How?

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED : I remarked only about `DllRegisterServer` and `DllUnregisterServer`, but yes, `DllGetClassObject` would need to be exported, you're correct.

Comment: @ildjarn: apologies. My remark was meant for TCS :)

Comment: @Mehrdad, @Mark - I guess you were right about the resources.
I used a different application (ResourceExtract) and it did extract .bin files (unlike the other resource explorer...).

Comment: Managed DLLs don't have any exports.  They can implement COM servers too, using mscoree.dll as the bootstrapper.  Kinda pointless to not mention the DLL name.

Comment: @Hans - its not managed (.Net).
Funny thing about microsoft, They tell the whole world to use .Net, but they continue to develop in C++ :-)

Comment: @TCS: If you had **millions** of lines of code in C and C++, would you switch to .NET and rewrite a large fraction of the code (or at least make some wrappers) because of it? Or would you just keep what's already working?

Comment: @Mehrdad, that's a good point, but I know that even new products are mainly being used in C++.
Although it still makes sense it is code reuse from other programs, just like you said....

Comment: @Hans: thanks. Learned something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of dealing with versions of a program destined for different languages is to put all of the resources into a language DLL. The DLL doesn't contain any code, just resources that have been translated to a target language. When the main program starts up, all it needs to do is load the proper language DLL.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't looked at the DLLs in question; but it's possible in something like MSOffice Microsoft have done this to obfuscate the DLL to make it more difficult to debug / reverse engineer.

However, as you ask how would you use such a DLL? Well if the application *knows* the layout of the DLL then it can create a function pointer with the address of a known function and call it.

If you really want to dig further you could objdump the DLL and look for standard C / C++ ABI function prologues & epilogues and possibly work out where the functions start.

Comment: I **really** doubt that Microsoft would do something like this. There are more important DLLs in the system that should be protected, but which aren't.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Perhaps; but the different teams in Microsoft are quite independant - and it's a huge company. Just because logically there are other apps / system DLLs which are more 'important' doesn't negate the possibility that Office does this.

Comment: @Dave: still doesn't make sense. The most likely reason is that they are resource DLLs as pointed out in another answer. Besides, the easiest point to start looking for code is: does it have an entry point (PE header).

Answer (score 3):

When you call LoadLibrary the DLL gets call of its DllMain. 
That is DLL entry point. It is called on process attach and thread attach. 
So you do have entry point.

As soon as it has at least one entry point then it can create instance of some interface (e.g. factory) an set it in e.g. TLS variables where other modules will pickup them.

So you can can have COM alike system of interfaces that are not exposed outside except to the application. Something like that - many over variations are possible.

Comment: _If_ there is an entry point in the DLL. Which was never stated either ;)

Comment: "Which was never stated either" - why?

Comment: perhaps because the entry point is not listed as export. Too few details on part of the OP, I say.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED : exe and dll entry points are always there and there is no need to export them. You will not see them in PE export list.

Or I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: c-smile: you're wrong, they're not always there for a DLL. But they're a good indicator whether the DLL is also going to run code or whether it merely contains some data. The respective setting in VS is `ResourceOnlyDLL` (`/noentry`) ...

Comment: To STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: Again, I do not understand what you are talking about. Check author's comments: "The DLLs doesn't contain any resources". So it is not a resource DLL. If it is not that it must have entry point otherwise it is useless.

Comment: c-smile: forget it, we're apparently not getting anywhere with this ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Resources

The DLL likely has resources, like string tables, images, icons, etc., used by the rest of Office.

Answer (score 1):

Always possible that they just don't export them as C interfaces. A DLL isn't magic, it's just bits and bytes, and nothing says that you can't get code out of a DLL if you don't ask Windows for it. I believe that .NET takes this approach- they save metadata in the DLL that tells the CLR what's in it, instead of making .NET functions available by the normal GetProcAddress approach. Unless you explicitly ask for it.

Comment: Can you please give sources for your statement about .NET. I don't really think "faith-based" statements like that in a Q&A format are reasonable ;) ... besides, a DLL is _not_ just bits and bytes. It's first and foremost following a particular format (PE) and although your theory about getting function pointers out of a DLL without exports could work, in practice it's a maintenance hell.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. So you mean something like a manifest that would describe where to find code blobs? Interesting. I feel an upcoming urge to launch my IDA Pro :)