# Possible to Interface with/use 3rd party Windows driver?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, drivers, etw

This touches on some already-answered questions, so feel free to duplicate away, but chances are I've already read them and am not satisfied.

There are 2 drivers on my system (located in C:\Windows\System32\drivers) called `pefndis.sys` and `wfpcapture.sys`.  I am 100% sure `pefndis.sys` is a kernel driver and 99.9% sure `wfpcature.sys` is as well.  These are 3rd party drivers installed by Mircosoft's Message Analyzer.  I have discovered `pefndis.sys` is used to capture data on the wire and `wfpcapture.sys` is used to capture data above the network layer (ie, this will capture loopback traffic).  I have no documentation, header files, etc, for these drivers as there was no intention of Microsoft for these drivers to be used for custom solutions as I would like to do.  It just so happens I've identified `wfpcapture.sys` as performing the exact tasks I want, and I'd love to tap into what it can do; this seems so much more reasonable than spending the time and pain of implementing my own driver.  However, my efforts have failed.

This is what I've done: I have some simple c++ code here:

```
void Provider::InitDriver()
{
   HANDLE wfpHandle = NULL;
   DWORD lastError = 0;

   LPCTSTR wfpName = L"\\\\.\\wfpcapture";
   LPCTSTR pefName = L"\\\\.\\pefndis";

   wfpHandle = CreateFile(
      wfpName,
      GENERIC_READ,
      FILE_SHARE_READ,
      NULL,
      OPEN_EXISTING,
      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
      NULL);

   lastError = GetLastError();

   CloseHandle(wfpHandle);
}
```

When I run `CreateFile` with `wfpName`, I get an invalid handle and `lastError==2` meaning the file cannot be found.  When I run `CreateFile` with `pefName`, I get a valid handle and `lastError==0`.  Upon further investigation, most of my randomly-picked `.sys` files from the `drivers` folder produce invalid handles with error codes of 2.  Occasionally I'd get an error code of 5 (Access Denied, which also seems odd since I'm running everything as administrator).  Does anyone have an explanation why I cannot get a handle to `wfpcapture.sys`?  I brought up the `pefndis.sys` driver because it was installed by the same program as `wfpcapture.sys`, and I can clearly get a handle to that, so all my strings are formatted correctly, and both files are in the same directory.  I came across [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ce06be76-af47-4990-9865-d3cc515be649/how-to-get-a-handle-to-a-device-driver-and-send-deviceiocontrol?forum=vcgeneral) yesterday which told me `IoCreateSymbolicLink` can be used in the driver code to give the driver another alias.  If I'm using the wrong alias, does that explain why so many `.sys` files return FILE_NOT_FOUND errors when I try to get handles to them?

I've tried to do some more research on the file using IL DASM (no luck, this is native code), DUMPBIN, [WinObj](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896657.aspx), and DependencyWalker.

`DUMPBIN /EXPORTS [...]wfpcapture.sys` returns no exports.  I find this extremely odd.  [These answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588249/dll-without-exported-functions) suggest .DLLs without exports are simply resources or the code is obfuscated.  I am almost certain `wfpcapture.sys` does not just contain resources.  Is obfuscation the most reasonable explanation.. any other ideas why it doesn't have any exports?

I could not find `wfpcapture` in WinObj anywhere.  I located `pefndis` in `Device\`.  Where is `wfpcapture`?  It doesn't actually talk to a device, so that makes sense, but it is still a driver, correct?  Do drivers need to register with Windows in some way before `CreateFile` can find them?

DependencyWalker verified what DUMPBIN told me, I think .. no exports.  I have no idea how Message Analyzer (or anything else down its dependency stack) is actually talking to it.

Just a bit more background for a complete picture... `wfpcapture.sys` is an ETW Provider that taps into Microsoft's WFP architecture (used for firewall and IDS applications) to sniff packets above the network layer.  I want code that "activates" `wfpcapture.sys` and then sits back and collects the events (packet captures) that `wfpcapture` publishes.  It's this activation part that I can't figure out.  If I setup Message Analyzer to start capturing localhost traffic, then turn on the part of my code that captures the events (using `StartTrace(...)` and `EnableTraceEx2(...)`), that works just fine.  I am just dying to know how Message Analyzer is talking to `wfpcapture.sys` and what it's saying in order to get it to cooperate and start publishing events.  Another fun fact: When I start a trace in Message Analyzer and do `sc query wfpcapture`, it tells me the service (here it is identified as a kernel driver) is running.  When I stop the trace, the query tells me the service is stopped.  If I manually `sc start wfpcapture` and verify the service is running,, and then run my event capturing code, I get nothing.  This tells me Message Analyzer **must** be sending something to `wfpcapture.sys` to get it activated and publishing.  My plan that spawned this whole thing was to get a handle to driver and start sending it control codes via `DeviceIoControl` to glean some knowledge on how it worked.  I have also seen some very strong evidence that Message Analyzer is passing filter masks to the driver.

Am I completely wasting my time here?  That driver is not meant for my consumption, and poking and prodding it to learn about it may be a long shot, but I'm certain it does **exactly** what I need and I've never written a driver in my life; trying to do that seems foolish when this is sitting right here.  Message Analyzer is free, I'm not trying to steal software.  Could there possibly be some DRM associated with the driver that's boxing me out?  I'd love to hear the thoughts of anyone out there who has Windows driver experience.

Ok, lot of questions there, hope this doesn't get flagged as too broad.

Comment: Wow that's a wall of text.  Let me see if I understand what you're on about...  You want to capture packets from the computer, and the solution you're working toward involves groveling into kernel drivers. The answer is don't. It's undocumented for a reason. Use WinPcap, or if you don't want to use it, look at how they do it. (It's open source after all)  Also `.sys != .dll`.

Comment: @theB heh, sorry, I know I get long winded.  I specifically want IPv6 loopback traffic on Windows for a custom app.  Perhaps diving into WinPcap would be easier. It's my understanding that loopback traffic doesn't go far enough down the stack in Windows for WinPcap to see it.  Message Analyzer captures all of this... just wish it had an API (it doesn't, I've asked).  I also got the idea from somewhere that `.sys` and `.dll` were basically the same thing, `.sys` was just used to indicate driver files.  I'll look more into that.

Comment: just in case anyone else stumbles across this.. I eventually figured this out by using IL DASM to comb through the CIL assembly code in the Message Analyzer .dlls, and found the function calls down to the driver that started and stopped capture.  There's more to the setup, but after all of that, calling `BeforeStart()` and `AfterStop()` will start and stop capture. These are in Microsoft.Opn.Runtime.Messaging.dll.

Comment: btw, http://batcmd.com/windows/10/services/wfpcapture/ says "Microsoft WFP Message Capture" (wfpcapture.sys) doesn't exist in "Version 1511"